# Suitable flying mounts with good or better maneuverability

Tags: dnd-3.5e, mount

I am looking for a flying mount for my character. I want a mount that is:

- Large (my character is medium, and I don't want one that can't squeeze through things I can go through)
- Good maneuverability or better. This is the one I am having trouble with, as I can't find a large animal with a decent fly speed with good maneuverability
- Decent fly speed (70+)
- Not too slow on the ground, at **least** a move speed of 30ft
- Can become a cohort. This is preferable but not necessary.

I understand that there is probably not a "perfect" mount for my character in the monster manual. My DM is very strict on CORE only, so please don't recommend animals that are not in the first MM

Comment: This is an extremely good question.  There are very few good flying mounts in 3.5, even outside core.  An authoritative answer on this topic would be a useful resource.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The nightmare is the only creature that as printed meets the criteria, but a half-celestial centaur, lamia, unicorn, or winter wolf can also easily meet the criteria. The giant bee and the spell *phantom steed*'s effect *almost* meet the criteria. Details below.

---

*Monster Manual* Large creatures with land speeds of at least 30 ft. *and* fly speeds of at least 70 ft. with good or perfect maneuverability include...

### Likely Choices

- The [**nightmare**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/nightmare.htm) (*MM* 194-5) with fly 90 ft. (good). Explicitly allowed to become a cohort, the nightmare has a Level Adjustment of +4 making the typical nightmare ECL 10. Further, unlike many other creatures on this list, it's horse-like and, despite its Intelligence score of 13, allows itself to be ridden by, for example, the night hag (*MM* 193-4).
- An appropriate creature with the template [**half-celestial**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/halfCelestial.htm) (*MM* 144-6) gains a fly speed equal to twice its base land speed and good maneuverability. (As opposed to the average maneuverability granted by the templates half-dragon (*MM* 146-7) and half fiend (*MM* 147-9).) The Level Adjustment for a creature with the template half-celestial is +4.

  *Monster Manual* Large creatures to which the half-celestial template can be applied with minimal fuss that then have a fly speed of at least 70 ft. include a **blink dog** (*MM* 28) advanced to at least 8 Hit Dice (minimum ECL 14), the **centaur** (*MM* 32) (ECL 10), an **ethereal filcher** (*MM* 104-5) advanced to at least 8 Hit Dice, an **ethereal marauder** (*MM* 105) advanced to at least 5 Hit Dice, an at least Large **fire elemental** (*MM* 98-99), a **formian warrior** (*MM* 109-10) advanced to at least 9 Hit Dice, a **formian taskmaster** (MM 109-10) advanced to at least 10 Hit Dice, the **formian myrmarch** (*MM* 110-1), the **guardian naga** (*MM* 192), a **krenshar** (*MM* 163) advanced to at least 5 Hit Dice (minimum ECL 11), the **leonal** (*MM* 142) advanced to at least 19 Hit Dice, the **phase spider** (*MM* 207-8), and the **unicorn** (*MM* 249-50) (ECL 12). Obviously, some of these make more sense than others. (A half-celestial centaur or unicorn? Sure. A half-celestial fire elemental or formian taskmaster? Not so much.)

  Because their alignments aren't usually compatible, creatures that are atypical prospects for the template half-celestial include the **achaieri** (*MM* 9-10), the **annis** (*MM* 143), the **dark naga** (*MM* 191-2), the **displacer beast** (*MM* 66-7) (ECL 14), the **frost giant** (*MM* 122-3) (ECL 22), a **hellhound** (*MM* 152-3) advanced to at least 9 Hit Dice (minimum ECL 16), the **howler** (*MM* 154-5) (ECL 13), the **lamia** (*MM* 165) (ECL 17), a **shadow mastiff** (*MM* 222) advanced to at least 7 Hit Dice (minimum ECL 18), the **spirit naga** (*MM* 192-3), the **winter wolf** (*MM* 256) (ECL 13), a **worg** (MM 256-7) advanced to at least 7 Hit Dice (minimum ECL 12), and a **xill** (*MM* 259-60) advanced to 9 Hit Dice (minimum ECL 17). Again, some of these make more sense than others. Also remember that even if a creature is listed as *always* being a certain alignment that *always* doesn't actually mean *always* (see Alignment on *MM* 305 and [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28050/8610)).

  > #### What about half-celestial animals?
  >
  > The core rules don't really support animals being the targets of the 5th-level Drd spell [*awaken*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/awaken.htm) [trans] (*PH* 202) *first* then somehow gaining the normally inherited template half-celestial *afterward*, but if the DM can be convinced this happens somehow or that awakened once-animal-now-outsiders naturally roam wild somehow or whatever, animals that after gaining the template half-celestial that have fly speeds of at least 70 ft. include the bison (*MM* 269-70), brown bear (*MM* 269), camel (*MM* 270), dire bear (*MM* 63), dire boar (*MM* 63), dire lion (*MM* 63), dire tiger (*MM* 65), dire weasel (*MM* 65) advanced to at least 7 Hit Dice, a dire wolf (*MM* 65-6), heavy horse (*MM* 273), heavy warhorse (*MM* 273-4), hyena (*MM* 274) advanced to at least 4 Hit Dice, light horse (*MM* 273), light war horse  (*MM* 274), polar bear (*MM* 269), lion (*MM* 274-5), tiger (*MM* 281-2), and wolf (*MM* 283) advanced to at least 4 Hit Dice.

  In all cases creatures without a listed ECL aren't given one here. The DM decides if a creature's ECL remains based on the creature's Hit Dice (like I've done here) when the creature's advanced to size Large; such a creature's *Challenge Rating* usually increase by an additional +1 when that happens (see Table 4–4: Improved Monster CR Increase on *MM* 294); what happens to its *Level Adjustment* is up to the DM.

  Thus the most likely and conservative choices are the ECL 10 [half-celestial](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/halfCelestial.htm) [centaur](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/centaur.htm) with fly 100 ft. (good) and the ECL 12 [half-celestial](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/halfCelestial.htm) [unicorn](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/unicorn.htm) with fly 120 ft. (good). Easily adjudicated but less likely to occur in nature are the ECL 13 [half-celestial](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/halfCelestial.htm) [winter wolf](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/winterWolf.htm) with fly 100 ft. (good) and the ECL 17 [half-celestial](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/halfCelestial.htm) [lamia](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/lamia.htm) with fly 120 ft. (good).

#### Interesting and very close

- The [**giant bee**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/giantBee.htm) (*MM* 284) advanced to at least 7 Hit Dice with fly 80 ft. (good). The giant bee's base land speed is only 20 ft., but listed here nonetheless because it's not a biped like the Unlikely Choices, below, and because the [*SRD*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/skills.htm#handleAnimal) says that a creature can take 6 months to make a Handle Animal skill check to rear vermin (DC 35 + vermin's Hit Dice) and 2 months to make a Handle Animal skill check to train vermin (DC 50 + the vermin's Hit Dice). Although listed in the *SRD*'s epic section, such DCs can be achieved by non-epic characters, especially if the DM allows a bunch of folks to [aid another](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/usingSkills.htm#combiningSkillAttempts) already skilled trainer.
- If willing to settle for a slightly slower fly speed, creatures that can speak and wear a shoulders slot magic item should be able to make use of the wondrous item [***wings of flying***](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#wingsofFlying) (*DMG* 268) (58,000 gp; 2 lbs.) to gain a speed of fly 60 ft. (good). However, I figure the speed of 70 ft. is precisely *to* outpace those folks relying on such an item or an effect like the spell [*fly*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/fly.htm), so that's probably not an option.
- The 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell [***phantom steed***](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/phantomSteed.htm) [conj] (*PH* 261) for 1 hour/level creates a quasireal horselike creature with a land speed of 20 ft./level (maximum 240 ft.). A level 12 caster's steed at will can use an effect like the 4th-level Clr spell [*air walk*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/airWalk.htm) [trans] (*PH* 196) except that it lasts 1 round and that it takes no action to employ. This gives the steed an effective fly-by-running-through-the-air speed of 240 ft. and an effective maneuverability of perfect, but the air walk effect makes it subject to strong winds, the steed has only 7 +1/level hp, the rider plummets if the steed's dispelled or reduced to 0 hp, and such a steed just can't be a cohort.

### Unlikely Choices

The DM may rule that these bipedal creatures aren't "suited for riding" so the rider suffers a −5 penalty on Ride skill checks when using one as a mount (*PH* 80). Otherwise, the following creatures meet the initial requirements, but their sheer power will likely make them unavailable as mounts.

- The **astral deva** (*MM* 11) advanced to at least 19 Hit Dice with fly 100 ft. (good). Minimum ECL 27.
- The **avoral** (*MM* 141-2) advanced to at least 15 Hit Dice with fly 90 ft. (good).
- The **balor** (*MM* 40-1) with fly 90 ft. (good).
- The **brilani** (*MM* 93-4) advanced to at least 13 Hit Dice with its fly 100 ft. (perfect). Minimum ECL 18.
- The **ghaele** (*MM* 94-5) advanced to 16 Hit Dice with its fly speed of 150 ft. (perfect).
- The **planetar** (*MM* 11-12) with fly 90 ft. (good).
- The **solar** (*MM* 12-13) with fly 150 ft. (good).
- The **trumpet archon** (*MM* 18-19) advanced to at least 19 Hit Dice with fly 100 ft. (good). Minimum ECL 27.

In all cases creatures without a listed Level Adjustment aren't given an ECL here. As listed under half-celestial, above, a creature that becomes Large has its CR increased by +1, and how this affects its LA is up to the DM.

Comment: You might want to add the *phantom steed* spell to the list. It's only available to those who can cast the spell, of course, but the *steed* gets *air walk* at will from caster level 10 - and *air walk* is very much like flight with perfect manoeuvrability, albeit with a weakness to wind speed and some limitations on changing altitude. Better, the *steed* can use this ability on other creatures it touches without an action, meaning you can **dismount in midair, walk on nothing for a bit to stretch your legs, then get back in the saddle and continue galloping across the sky.** Classy, right?

Comment: @GMJoe Thanks for the heads-up on *phantom steed.* Information added. But having the steed use *air walk* (or, even more confusingly, *water walk*) on another creature is a burden better assumed by its own question rather than addressed here. Kudos, though, for bringing to my attention a rules quirk about which I was unaware. Classy indeed.

Comment: Suggestions for improvement welcome.

Comment: Thank you so much for linking all the creatures! This really made it a lot easier!